# Scrape data from multiple tables with same id and class using Python Scrapy

Tags: python, html, scrapy, lxml

I have a webpage(https://enr-apps.as.cmu.edu/open/SOC/SOCServlet/search) with an HTML table as follows:

```
<table id="search-results-table" class="table table-condensed table-striped">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th class="col-course">Course</th>
     <th class="col-title">Course Title</th>
     <th class="col-units">Units</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  .....
  .....
```

I am trying to extract the rows of this table as follows:

```
for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="search-results-table"]//tbody/tr'):
yield {
     'course': row.xpath('normalize-space(td[1]//text())').extract_first(),
     'title': row.xpath('normalize-space(td[2]//text())').extract_first(),
     'units': row.xpath('normalize-space(td[3]//text())').extract_first(),
       }
```

This works as expected.However, there is more than one table with the same id.What I tried then was to find the count of the occurence of table and add an outer loop with index as follows:

```
count = len(response.xpath('//*[@id="search-results-table"]').getall())
for index in range(count):
    for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="search-results-table"]//tbody/tr')[index]:
        yield {
           'course': row.xpath('normalize-space(td[1]//text())').extract_first(),
           'title': row.xpath('normalize-space(td[2]//text())').extract_first(),
           'units': row.xpath('normalize-space(td[3]//text())').extract_first(),
         }
```

However, this does not work with the following error:

```
for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="search-results-table"]//tbody/tr')[index]:
TypeError: 'Selector' object is not iterable
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: how else do i do it..

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy write correct code for you case without the link to site.

But you can read your exception:

```
for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="search-results- table"]//tbody/tr')[index]:
TypeError: 'Selector' object is not iterable
```

Realy, you are trying to get element by index from `Selector`. You need a collection for this.

Few lines above you used `.getall()` method and you get list of elements filtered by selector. Try use this method again.

**Note!** But that's not your whole problem. Then, probably, you'll get not correct result because few lines above you used one selector and then another.

Comment: updated the question with the website..you will though have to hit submit to get to the results page

Comment: @Amistad, first try to fix your problem yourself. I have made necessary notes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're also open to other solutions: I suggest using `pandas` `read_html` which loads all html tables into a list of dataframes:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = { 'SEMESTER': 'M21', 'MINI': 'NO', 'GRAD_UNDER': 'All', 'PRG_LOCATION': 'All', 'DEPT': 'All', 'LAST_NAME': '', 'FIRST_NAME': '', 'BEG_TIME': 'All', 'KEYWORD': '', 'TITLE_ONLY': 'YES', 'SUBMIT': '' }
r = requests.post('https://enr-apps.as.cmu.edu/open/SOC/SOCServlet/search', data=data)
df = pd.read_html(r.content)
```

You can access the dataframes with `df[0]`, `df[1]`, etc.